# Styling Label inside another control

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms, having a XAML code: (an example below) is it possible to move the style of the Label and the Image to appplication level style and make it default for all Expander headers (or other containers)?

```
<xct:Expander>
                        <xct:Expander.Header>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label
                                    Margin="20,10,0,10"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    Text="ABCD"
                                    TextTransform="Uppercase"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                <Image
                                    Margin="0,0,20,0"
                                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <FontImageSource
                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource Font_FASolid}"
                                            Glyph="{x:Static fonts:FASolid.ChevronDown}"
                                            Size="{StaticResource MediumFontSize}" />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </xct:Expander.Header>
                    </xct:Expander>
```

What I would like to have in my xaml finally is just:

```
<xct:Expander>
<xct:Expander.Header>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="ABCD"/>
        <Image>
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Expander.Header></xct:Expander>
```

Comment: That seems impossible.But you can use the [global style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) to declare the style in the Application.Resources. And use it in the page.xaml or in the page.class.

Comment: why dont you create a content view for your expander header .